# How to edit PKGBUILD in aura?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, editing

My question is about an Archlinux AUR helper, - aura.
I tried to edit a PKGBUILD file before installing a package, but could not: no keys that I use in text editors are working.

What keys are used to edit PKGBUILD when aura is invoked with --hotedit option?

1) How to delete a character?

2) How to insert a digit?

3) How to save changes and exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really about the AUR helper – it's about the editor it invokes. Aura doesn't have a built-in text editor, it just runs whatever program you set in the **$EDITOR** environment variable, and **vi** if nothing was configured. (Most command-line programs do the same.)

*Vi* is a modal editor, with separate "command" and "insert" modes – you need to press <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd> before inserting text, and return with <kbd>Esc</kbd> afterwards. (You can delete text with <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd> in command mode though.) When you're in command mode, the `:wq [Enter]` command will save and exit; `:q! [Enter]` will exit without saving.

Quite inconveniently, vi doesn't show the current mode anywhere and is a bit too strict about the meaning of "insert mode", so I'd really recommend you to install Vim or Nano and use `export EDITOR=vim` or **`export EDITOR=nano`**. (Nano is the easier one, but even Vim isn't as bad as vi.)